# some devices do not return current latitude longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, location, latitude-longitude

I am trying to get the address of the user, for that i need the current latitude and longitude of the user. I am using following code for the same

```
public LatLng getCurrentLocation(Context context) {
    try {
        LocationManager locMgr = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        String locProvider = locMgr.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(locProvider);

        // getting GPS status
        boolean isGPSEnabled = locMgr
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        // getting network status
        boolean isNWEnabled = locMgr
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNWEnabled) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Network and GPS are unavailable");
            // no network provider is enabled
            return null;
        } else {
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNWEnabled) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Network is enabled for getting the location");
                if (locMgr != null) {
                    Log.v(TAG,
                            "Location manager is not null so fetch the location from network");
                    location = null;
                    location = locMgr
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    if (locMgr != null)
                        location = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                }
            }
        }
        return new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Current Lat Lng is Null");
        return new LatLng(0, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new LatLng(0, 0);
    }
}
```

In my Moto e with android 4.4 it is working very good but in some of the devices it does not return the lat lng and i get 0,0 which is returned in the exception. 
What i need to change to get it correct in all devices.

Comment: Looks like you might be getting an exception.  Maybe you can find a way to send an exception log from the device (assuming you don't have physical access to it).  Either save it to a remote database such as parse.com, or email it to yourself.

Comment: For get the `current location`, instead of use `LocationManager`, you can use `FusedLocationApi`, it will more accurate. Take look at [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-location-android), and get code from [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/getLastLocationUsingGPS-android)